# Google App Script Catch Row Number

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I have looked everywhere and seen the related questions on this board, but I am really stuck.

I need to capture the actual row value of a Sheet at is iterates through a for loop based on an if statement.

In other parts of the code, I have to create a copy of a Form's response sheet and move it to a folder.  I am trying to log the file id of the new file that is being created to a sheet that already exists (and in which the scripts are being called from a menu).

I can get the data and the values and iterate through them and see everything in the Logs.  And based on what I saw in other similar questions and such, I tried the getActiveRange().getRow() part - but it only works for the exact row that the cursor is on when the form is open.  I need to be able to dynamically set the ActiveRow variable based on the row that the script is currently looking at as it goes through the for loop.

I can not use the for loop variable as my current row (j+1), because the if statement is only looking for a string value "NOT FOUND" in the column - so the "j" variable value would not necessarily match the row value to update.

Thank you so much for any assistance!!

```
 // Get the active spreadsheet and the active sheet
 var ssEXD = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('FormData');
 var lastRowEXD = ssEXD.getLastRow();
 var lastColumnEXD = ssEXD.getLastColumn();
 var formIDValues = ssEXD.getSheetValues(2, 1, lastRowEXD-1, lastColumnEXD);

 //Loop through the returned values
 for(var j = 0; j < formIDValues.length; j++) {    

   //if NOT FOUND is true, do stuff
   if (formIDValues[j][6] == "NOT_FOUND") {

     //need this variable to be the exact row of the sheet value data
     var ActiveRow = ssEXD.getActiveRange().getRow();
     //I need to use the ActiveRow in the getActiveRange to update the sheet with some information. 
     ssEXD.getRange(ActiveRow,6,1).setValue("testing"); 

   } 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly your data has a column names on the first row and data begins on the second row.

So I think this will accomplish what you want.

```
 var ssEXD = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('FormData');
 var lastRowEXD = ssEXD.getLastRow();
 var lastColumnEXD = ssEXD.getLastColumn();
 var dataR = ssEXD.getDataRange();
 var dataA = dataR.getValues();
 for(var j = 1; j < dataA.length; j++) 
 {    
   if (dataA[j][6] == "NOT_FOUND") 
   {
     dataA[j][6] = "testing";
   }
 }  
 dataR.setValues(dataA);
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, thank you for the response and the code update.  For anyone looking at this, just a reminder to update your array column value as you are starting with 1 and not zero.  Took me a minute on that.  A follow up question so that I understand it.  How does the setValues method keep track of the rows outside for the for or if loop?  How does that work?? Thank you for pointing me in the right way - especially with re-setting the variable in the if statement.

Comment: Rows and Columns in the spreadsheet start at one.  Row and Columns in the array created by getValues() start at zero. So the data in the cell at row=1 and column=1 is the same data as dataA[0][0].  When you do setValues() make sure that the dataR is the same size.  And the array has to be 2 dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ActiveRow = j + 2;
```

Once an array(formIDValues) has been extracted from sheet, the array has no more relation to that sheet. One must adjust the index of the item being worked on in the array to the row number in the spreadsheet.

j - the array index  - starts at zero which is the second row in this spreadsheet, therefore j + 2

Your concern about the j variable is unwarranted. j is incremented for every pass through the loop whether or not any test has been passed.